# JSP - Button for every entry in ForEach loop

Tags: jsp

Here is my code - JSP file which is using provided Attribute (candidates):

```
<% ArrayList<Candidate> candidates = (ArrayList<Candidate>) request.getAttribute("candidates"); %>

   <% for (int i = 0; i<candidates.size(); i++) { %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Imię</b></td>
        <td> <%= candidates.get(i).getFirstName() %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Nazwisko</b></td>
        <td> <%= candidates.get(i).getLastName() %>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>PESEL</b></td>
        <td> <%= candidates.get(i).getPESEL() %>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Płeć</b></td>
        <td><%= candidates.get(i).getSex() %>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Miasto</b></td>
        <td><%= candidates.get(i).getCity() %>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Adres</b></td>
        <td><%= candidates.get(i).getAddress() %>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Numer kontaktowy</b></td>
        <td><%=candidates.get(i).getContactNumber() %>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Adres e-mail</b></td>
        <td><%= candidates.get(i).getEmailAddress() %>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Umiejętności</b></td>
        <td><%= candidates.get(i).getExperiences() %>
</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<form action="JobOfferServlet" method="post">
<% Integer id = candidates.get(i).getId(); %>
<input type="hidden" name="candidateId" value="<%= id%>">
    <button type="submit" name="option" value="listMatching">Znajdz oferty pracy dla
<%= candidates.get(i).getFirstName()%> <%= candidates.get(i).getLastName()%></button>
    <br><br>
<% } %>
```

What I'm trying to do here:
I want to show every Candidate out of candidates ArrayList and in addition - add specified button for every entry which will forward Candidate's ID along with option parameter specifying needed outcome in Servlet class.

Problem is, no matter which button I clicked, send ID is always 1 - and the action is performed for the first Candidate on the list even though every Candidate is printed in browser properly, even on button's label...

First i tried with ForEach JSP loop, when with basic For loop but the effect is the same - always 1st Candidate is used.

How can I make it work?

Comment: I don't see a form closing tag (</form>) in your loop. Do you have it? Because this way, only one form is created.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt OMG. I can't believe I missed that. You're right, I forgot about form closing tag. I probably accidently delete it after refactoring the class and blame it on stupid JSP scriplets... turned out I was the one that was stupid. Thanks mate, I really appreciate it cause I was stuck for 2 evenings with this issue.

Comment: You're welcome. If you mark my answer as accepted, I would be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a form closing tag `</form>` in your loop. Otherwise, only one form is created and at all events, the same values are submitted.